Ошибка во время деплоя модели градиентного спуска для задачи классификации текста
Для задачи классификации текста использовал модель SGD(ноутбук). Начал деплоить. Но возникла не понятная ошибка. Шаги:

Сериализация модели

    joblib.dump(SGDClassifier, 'spam_sgd_model.pkl')        
    joblib.dump(vectorizer, 'tfidf_vectorizer_model.pkl')  
    joblib.dump(sc, 'standard_scaler_model.pkl')


Подключение FastAPI

    from fastapi import FastAPI  
    app = FastAPI()


Построение Deployment API

    import joblib  
    from pydantic import BaseModel  
    model_load = joblib.load('spam_sgd_model.pkl')  
    vectorizer_load = joblib.load('tfidf_vectorizer_model.pkl')  
    scaler_load = joblib.load('standard_scaler_model.pkl')  

    class Email(BaseModel):  
        text: str  
      
    @app.post("/predict/")  
    async def predict(email: Email):  
        text_vectorized = vectorizer_load.transform([email.text])  
        text_scaled = scaler_load.transform(text_vectorized)  
        prediction = model_load.predict(text_scaled)  
        return {"prediction": int(prediction[0])}  


Хостинг

    nest_asyncio.apply()    
    if __name__ == "__main__":  
        import uvicorn  
        uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080) 

Далее решил потестить работу программы и запустил в отдельном поле код:
    import requests
    
    sample_text = "viiiiiiagraaaa only for the ones that want to make her scream. prodigy scrawny crow define upgrade. caant do..."
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/predict/"
    
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json={"text": sample_text})
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an error for bad status codes
        print(response.json())
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_err:
        print(f"Request error occurred: {req_err}")
    except ValueError as json_err:
        print(f"JSON decode error: {json_err}")
        print("Response content:", response.text)

В итоге возникла неожиданная ошибка(полный текст ошибки в ноутбуке по ссылке сверху):
    File "C:\Users\Murad Mammadzade\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12564\220705840.py", line 8, in predict
            prediction = model_load.predict(text_scaled)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        TypeError: LinearClassifierMixin.predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Попробовал уже разные методы + ChatGPT, но тщетно.

Тут ошибка в сериализации модели 'spam_sgd_model.pkl'. Вместо того чтобы вставить уже обученную модель под названием model, вставлена необученная модель градиентного спуска SGDClassifier, в этом и вся ошибка.
